# tests unexpectedly stopped working , they produce the following error [Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException] in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, functional-testing, codeception

yesterday worked perfectly and approved the test, now there continues after line 2 with the following error

```
[Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException]
```

Codeception:

"codeception/codeception": "^2.2@dev"

My functional.suite.yml

```
class_name: FunctionalTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Laravel5:
            environment_file: .env
        - \Helper\Functional
```

My test

```
$I = new FunctionalTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('visit to home');
$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->click(['class' => 'button-register']);
$I->see('Registrarme con Facebook');
```

My link

```html
<li class="header-menu-list-item trigger"><a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-transparent button-register trigger" data-dialog="modal-register">Regístrate</a> </li>
```

Comment: Laravel5 module does not support javascript - clicking on the link with href="javascript:;" makes no sense.

Comment: thanks, that's the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Following the comment [Naktibalda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366348/naktibalda) javascript replaced it with # and testing they worked properly